# How to hide elements from a dropdown menu based on other values?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-foundation, css

I have a dropdown field showing the following options: *Updated, Reviewed, Rejected*. However, I like certain options to be hidden at certain stages, is this possible?

For example, if `varStatus == Pending` then show dropdown only: `Updated` and hide the others. If `varStatus == In Review` then show dropdown option: `Reviewed` only and hide others... etc.

The dropdown field is called `varConcept` and the status `varStatus`

```
NWF$(document).ready(function(){  
 var currentStatus = NWF$('#' + varStatus);
 var conceptValue = NWF$('#' + varConcept);
 currentStatus.ready(function(){  
      if(currentStatus == Pending){  
        ... show conceptValue 'Updated' 
        otherwise hide all values
        if(currentStatus == In Review){
          show conceptValue 'Reviewed' and hide all other values

       }
      }  

 });
```

**UPDATE**

To explain this further:

There is a fieldname (not a dropdown) named `varConcept` and may contain values such as `Pending`, `In Review`, `Accepted`, `In Work`.

There is a dropdown menu named `varConcept` which holds following options: `Updated, Reviewed, Already Implemented, Duplicate, Assigned` and the idea behind all this is to make a script that checks the `varStatus` and shows relevant options in the dropdown `varConcept`.

In simple context:

```
IF varStatus contains "Pending" then show varConcept options Updated and Duplicate
IF varStatus contains "In Review" then show varConcept options Reviewed and Already Implemented
IF varStatus contains "Accepted" then show varConcept options Assigned
else hide everything
```

Comment: As you are using the jQuery-library, you can take us of the hide() and show() method: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: @SteffPoint right ... if I knew how to, I would not ask for support :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trial and errors, I got it working:

```
NWF$(document).ready(function() { 
   if (NWF$('#' + varStatus).val() == 'Pending' )
    {
      NWF$("#"+ varConcept).find("option[value='Pending']").remove();
      NWF$("#"+ varConcept).find("option[value='Reviewed']").remove();      
    }
   if (NWF$('#' + varStatus).val() == 'In Review' )
    {
      NWF$("#"+ varConcept).find("option[value='Pending']").remove();
      NWF$("#"+ varConcept).find("option[value='Updated']").remove();
       }
});
```

There is no code to say 'hide everything' if outside the above scope... feel free to add a comment if you got the answer to that.